# Cant install php 5.4.4 on ubuntu or parallels plesk panel 11

Tags: php, ubuntu, panel, plesk

I wonder how I can install PhP 5.4.4 on either ubuntu 10.04.4 or parallels plesk panel 11.

I just ordered a VPS running ubuntu with plesk panel, but the problem is that my plesk use php 5.3 and I need php 5.4.4 .

I have tried a few guides but I cant get it to work : /

Anyone here who has a good guide on how to do this?

Comment: What guides did you follow? What steps did you have issues with? Also, voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: this :
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=72042.htm

and it says:
Obtain the PHP source you need from the official website (http://php.net/downloads.php) and unpack it:
gunzip php-NN.tar.gz
tar -xf php-NN.tar

But how do I obtain / unpack it?
Im working on my mac via ssh terminal so access my ubuntu vps

Comment: That page is pretty explanitory... you need to go to the php site and find the download url of the source for the version you want to install, then either download it locally and upload it to the server, or use something like `wget` or `curl` to download it directly on the server... then follow the rest of the directions to uncompress the file and compile/install the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So go to the php download page and find the `tar.gz` version of the file you want. Clicking on it should give you a list of mirrors ill use wget https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.17.tar.gz/from/us1.php.net/mirror as the mirror for 5.4.17. Copy the url for the mirror you want to use. Then ssh into the server and:

`wget https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.17.tar.gz/from/us1.php.net/mirror`

This will download the file `php-5.4.17.tar.gz` to the working directory on the server.

Unpack the file:

`tar -xvzf php-5.4.17.tar.gz`

No you will have the directory structure mentioned in the installation instructions you linked to so you can just follow them from there (step 3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, working on it now.

getting the error:

root@vendioo:~# tar -xvzf php-5.4.17.tar.gz
tar: php-5.4.17.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: if you do `ls` do you see that file listed? you need to give the full path to the file. In my example i was in the same directory as the file but if its not in the same directory youre working from then you would need to use the full path like `/path/to/php-5.4.17.tar.gz`...